# Can't connect with Filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I just upgraded to the latest Filezilla version - and I can't connect to my websites. I keep getting a "connection timed out" error.

I discovered some sort of "Configuration" feature, so I gave it a try, but I can't copy and paste the results, because the screen closes when I try to copy the text (a very useful feature). However, it did say I had the "wrong external IP address."

I was invited to get the correct IP address on [this page](http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php). So I typed in that value, but I still get the same results - a connection timed out error and wrong external IP address.

I can connect to my websites fine with Dreamweaver, but not with Filezilla. Does anyone know what the solution is? If not, can you recommend any other FTP clients, preferably something free (or very inexpensive) and user friendly?

P.S. I was going to ask this on Filezilla's forum, but I couldn't register because they don't accept registration from people using Google's e-mail service. WTF???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check that FileZilla is defaulting to plain FTP (rather than SFTP, or some other protocol). If it is working properly in Dreamweaver I would open them both up and check to make sure the settings are all the same.

And if you would like to try a different FTP client I would recommend [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en).

Comment: I gave up on FileZilla and bought CyberDuck. At least, it comes with an authentic support platform. ;)